# UITextView resizes the height dynamically with restricting maximum height

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextview

I want to make the textview like `whatsapp` that resizing the textview's height when typing a long string. But once it reaches to the maximum height, the textview's will be remained to the maximum height and the textview becomes scrollable. It is exactly the same as `whatsapp`'s textview when replying message.

I found a way to resize dynamically, but when I set `textView.isScrollEnabled = true` once it reaches to the maximum height, the textview will shrink but be scrollable.

How can I make the textview exactly like `whatsapp`'s textview?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateHeight), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidChange, object: nil)
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    // ...
}

func updateHeight() {
    var contentSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.bounds.size)
    contentSize.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    if contentSize.height > UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 5{
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        contentSize.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 5
    } else {
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
    textView.frame.size = contentSize
}
```

[image]

Comment: R u using Autolayouts? If yes which constraints you have given?

Comment: textView.top = tableView.buttom

Comment: If you have given height constraint then take an outlet for it and change its constant instead of setting frame every time.It will work.

Comment: but the tableview hasn't a fixed height.

Comment: if the textView.isScrollEnabled = false, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension ViewController : UITextViewDelegate{

  func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool{

    let cursorPosition = self.textView.caretRect(for: self.tvChat.selectedTextRange!.start).origin
    let currentLine = Int(cursorPosition.y / self.tvChat.font!.lineHeight)

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        if currentLine == 0 {
            self.constraintHeightTextView.constant = 56
        }else {
            self.constraintHeightTextView.constant = self.textView.contentSize.height + 8 // Padding
        }
    }
    self.textView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.view.updateConstraints()
  }
}
```

**self.constraintHeightTextView** is an outlet for textview's height constraint.

As the text changes in textview you can calculate the current line of text you are working on and update its constraint to default (56 in my case) if **currentLine** is 0 else set it to textView.contentSize.height.

Hope it helps

Comment: i use your solution of using constraint of textview's height and put this piece of code in my updateHeight(), it works. thanks.

Comment: @CarlHung can you please add the full piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var textViewContentSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.bounds.size)
```

This will returns you the minimum size required of the `UITextView` to show all the contents in it.

and for restriction use below code

```
if textViewContentSize.height > 200{
   textViewContentSize = CGSize(width: textViewContentSize.height, height: 200)
}
```

So now your `textview` frame is as below,

```
textView.frame = CGRect(origin: textView.frame.origin, size: textViewContentSize)
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i think the problem is textView.isScrollEnabled = true, that will make the whole textview shrinks to the height of one line. but when i insert print("Height: \(contentSize.height)"), it prints out the height of the textview that should be(depends on how many lines).

Comment: this returns a fixed size textview. not dynamically changing the height.

Comment: @CarlHung It returns the size of the content in the textView. If you set `textView.isScrollEnabled = false` then think what when you wanted to restrict the `textView.height`. It doesn't restricts you to set the height.

Comment: ok, if textView.isScrollEnabled = false, my code would resize dynamically according to the length of the string. but if i set it to true, the textview will go back to height of one line. do you know what i mean?

Comment: @CarlHung write 50 line in your textview and tell me what is the output UI you got. Obviously textView takes size of 50 lines and your tableView get smaller.

Comment: your code also makes the value of height changed according to how many lines. but also same as what happened to me. on appearance, the height won't change.

Comment: same case as mine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139252/discussion-between-agent-stack-and-carl-hung).